Ghostscript is not working with imagick error FailedToExecuteCommand
I have PHP Laravel script working with following configuration.
Laragon
Apache httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16
PHP 8.3
Ghostscript 10.04.0
ImageMagick 7.1.0-18 Q16 x64

When I tried to convert pdf into image using exec command it works.
$pdfPath = $cvFile;
$outputPath = 'd:/temp/test.png';
$gsCommand = "gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r144 -sOutputFile=\"$outputPath\" \"$pdfPath\"";
exec($gsCommand, $output, $returnCode);

But it doesn't works when I tried to convert pdf using Imagick().
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($cvFile);

I got this error when I tried the execute the above code on line readImage().

FailedToExecuteCommand `"gs" -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dPrinted=false "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/alish/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-fzsvjp49WgV_dLqdzA-KMiGFzpNpmnvQ%d" "-fC:/Users/alish/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-dC4PEbPqgCO7mlsy_cDaOIWgVTrR6Ixu" "-fC:/Users/alish/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-EJa1tcrtqJ9dcGUOrY2gv7--rqFtZS21"' (The system cannot find the file specified. ) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516

Imagick should able to convert pdf into image using Ghostscript.

Since Ghostscript works from the command shell, this clearly isn't a Ghostscript problem so I've removed the tag. Actually... Unless you've done something to get a binary named 'gs', then neither of these command lines should work. On windows the Ghostscript executable is called gswin(32|64).exe Depending on whether you have installed a 32 or 64 bit executable, and are using the (c)ommand line or windowed version. I doubt the 'exec' command is really working. You probably need to reconfigure ImageMagick to call the correct executable.

@KenS i have added gs.bat which run gswin64c.exe file, that is why gs command is working

Then you're going to have to dig more information out of ImageMagick, as to which file 'the system' can't find. @rozsazoltan, those old issues were resolved years ago. Notice that the error message in those reports is different " (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462".

Check your Imagemagick policy.xml file to be sure you have permissions to read PDF files. See https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php
